# MAC, GIT - Unable to unlink old : Permission denied error

Tags: git, macos, macos-high-sierra

MAC - macos High Sierra
GIT

In sourcetree, If I try to reset a file, I'm getting Permission denied error,

```
error: unable to unlink old 'path/to/item/File1.java': 
Permission denied
Completed with errors, see above
```

Getting the same error if I try to do merge in Terminal as well.

Tried lot of solutions from SO like executing

```
sudo chmod -RN . 
git reset --hard
sudo chmod -R ug+w .;    , but no luck.
```

My local repository is under /Users/myname/GIT/myproj/

PS: I installed macos High Sierra 2 days before this problem, I don't know if this upgrade is causing problem any way. It was working fine 
on previous OS Sierra.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: It's possible there is a process that has an open file handle to that file.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I tried that as well. Closed Eclipse and all other applications, gave a restart and kept only the SourceTree open.

Comment: If you do `lsof | grep File1.java`, do you get any results?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth No results.

Comment: I observed one more thing, when I tried to delete a file, which got this problem, manually in Finder, mac asked for username/pwd, but didn't delete the file. I followed some instructions from Apple website https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538 and after that could delete manually.

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting.  It sounds like you've got some rogue permissions somewhere :/  (Unfortunately, I don't know of an easy way to diagnose the problem at this point.)

Comment: Try rename your file to `file1.java` (notice the f minuscule) to see if it helps?

Comment: @VinhVO I moved my repo to a different location, like /opt/GIT/ and no more permission issues. Looks like MAC doesn't like files under /Users/ directory.